# Cocoa equivalent of diskEvt/kEventClassVolume?

Tags: macos, cocoa, volume, nsworkspace, diskarbitration

We have a drop-down menu of volumes in our UI, and I'd like to update it when a new disk is mounted. In the Classic days, this would involve watching for a `diskEvt` event. In Carbon, I think this was `kEventClassVolume`. What's the Cocoa equivalent?

(A pointer into Apple's documentation on this would satisfy the question. I've been unable to find anything!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSWorkspace posts [`NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification` and friends](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification) on [its notification center](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/notificationCenter).

Answer (score 0):

Disk Arbitration is responsible for those notifications. It's not written in Cocoa.

Comment: It does have an API, though: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/